# Using getDefaultSharedPreferences, having issues with Context

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am trying to use getDefaultSharedPreferences as I only have 3-4 bits of bool data to save (first ever app), according to the docs it needs...

"getDefaultSharedPreferencesName (Context context)"

So delving into the docs on context I reasoned that all I need to to give it was Context as this will be the context for my fragment, so I tried

```
 val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)
```

However I get the error

"Classifier 'Context' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here".

Googleing around there does not seem to be a lot of examples of getDefaultSharedPreferences out there. Can anybody help  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the line you posted in the question is that you are not passing the `context` value, but the `Context` type. Make sure to use the context with small 'c'

```
- val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)
+ val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fragment use `getActivity()` as context.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `Application` Context for providing `SharedPreferences`. You should use contex of `Application` class in your app.